# How can I use Nikon D3100 at -9°C?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3100, weather

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I consider when using DSLRs in cold weather?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5664/what-should-i-consider-when-using-dslrs-in-cold-weather)

I am visiting China and where the temperature is @ -9 degree Celsius. How can I use my Nikon D3100 DSLR over there?? Could any one advice me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also: [What should I consider when using DSLRs in cold weather?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5664/4390)