# How well will a nonweatherproof Canon Rebel DSLR hold up in the cold and snow?

Tags: canon, cold, environmental-dangers, weather-sealing

I'm going to Prague for a week and I'll be all day out in the cold and in the snow. I have a Canon 600D and I just discovered that my camera is not weatherproof. Is it safe for my camera? At the hotel, the temperature will be at least 20C, and outside not more than 5 maximum, so what am I supposed to do? Can I still use my camera?

Comment: See also [What should I consider when using DSLRs in cold weather?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5664/what-should-i-consider-when-using-dslrs-in-cold-weather) for a more general version of the same question.

Answer (score 4):

1. Check the specs of your camera wrt temperature. If Canon says it'll be fine, bring a couple spare batteries because cold saps battery power.
2. As for the temperature difference between outside and inside, what you need to worry about is condensation on the camera + lens. This will occur whenever a much colder item is moved into a warmer environment. The solution is to put your camera inside an airtight bag (a double layer of Ziplocs should do) *before* you enter the warm environment. Wait until the temperature of the camera has reached room temperature before opening.

Comment: Officially most cameras seem to be certified only down to zero degrees Celsius. This is a very conservative lower bound and as a Finn I'd be seriously pissed off if my camera couldn't handle shooting outside in the winter. Fortunately, in practice DSLRs can take -20 or -30 like champs - if anything, the cold will mitigate thermal noise in long exposures. Battery life *is* an issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

Think Tank Photo makes a product that protects your camera from the elements:

http://www.thinktankphoto.com/products/hydrophobia-70-200-rain-cover.aspx

Comment: That only protects against weather, not against condensation.