# Do I need anything special to shoot a timelapse in -10 degrees Celsius?

Tags: timelapse, cold

Will I be able to shoot 1-2 hours timelapse in -10 / -5 degrees Celsius? What should I worry about, lens, camera, battery (obviously), memory card?

Can I do anything if I don't have a specialised lens warmer?

Comment: What camera are you using?

Comment: Relevant, near duplicate: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5664/9161

Answer (score 1):

Most cameras can function at that temperature, but battery life is much reduced. You can buy an external battery-grip for some cameras, e.g. [this Nikon battery for the D750](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NJ0R43O) for ~US$340. I made a larger external battery pack for a Panasonic FZ1000 from [a DC adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005P6Q5XK) and a [few 18650 cells](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B079RTBN4D), below for ~US$50.

[image: Battery pack]

**N.B.**

- It is safest to use a battery holder or alligator clips to charge each parallel group, rather than trying to charge them in series, to avoid balancing issues.
- Put a small fuse near the battery to avoid high current and to reduce fire hazard.
- Do not put a cold camera or electronics in a warm room without protection from condensation! A large sealable plastic bag can prevent moisture on the lens and inside.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the camera.

From personal experience, my DSLR (Canon T6) didn't like much when I tried to use it, unprotected, at -17c. I felt the shutter getting slower, not sure if it actually was.

My GoPro session 5, on the other hand, took it like a champ. (Video here: https://youtu.be/D14KsdosU7E ). Most gopros have timelapse mode, and I know that the session can do about 1h30mins of timelapse with the internal battery. I hook it up to power or to an external USB battery if I want more than that.

My point being: That's GoPro territory. That damn thing works even inside liquid nitrogen. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZFpJ6DnWrg - that smaller one, without the screen is the session)