# EOS RP at freezing temperature

Tags: canon, equipment-protection

I'm going to Alaska next week and plan to bring my Canon RP with me to take pictures. It will be quite cold there (my weather says around 0°F-10°F for next week). Will this type of temperature wreck my camera? I plan to use the ziplock bag trick, but not sure if this kind of entry-level camera can survive that freezing temp. Anyone has shot their RP at 0°F before? Did it damage your camera?

Comment: What does the camera manual say about operating tempature?  Even if the camera is able to function at below freezing tempertures, the batteries may not.

Comment: out of curiosity, what is the "ziplock bag trick"?

Comment: I did more than once operate a Nikon D5100 (entry level camera) in something like -12°C for a few hours. For example on a 3 hour winter hike. I never noticed any issues. However it is very important to take out the battery and let the camera dry when you bring it back into the warm.

Comment: @osullic, you place the camera in a sealed bag before bringing it into a warmer/more humid environment (indoors) and leave it there until it comes up to temp... prevents condensation on/in the camera/lens.

Comment: @osullic I believe the "ziplock bag trick" is placing your camera in a sealed plastic bag while outdoors, before entering a building. When you enter a building condensation will not occur on the camera since the dew point temperature in the bag is the same as outdoors. Takes about 45 minutes for the camera temperature to equalize to the indoor temperature.

Comment: We've got a LOT of existing "cold weather" questions here. The accepted answer to this one, [Can lenses be damaged by rapid temperature and/or humidity changes?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/102978/15871) , has links to at least a dozen of them that talk about not only lenses but camera bodies as well.

Comment: @osullic Searching Photo SE for *ziplock bag* yields the following question with the highest vote total: [Camera bags for winter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6511/15871).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environmental specifications are a "guarantee" that your equipment will work as expected in the given environment. If you have any problems outside of that range, you were forewarned by the manufacturer.

That said, I have used my DSLR (Nikon D7000) down to -20°C (-5°F) for full days. I have also used this camera in -6 to 4°C (20 to 40°F) for 2 weeks while camping without issue. No attempt was made to keep the camera warm. Specifications for my camera are 0 to +40°C. On the other extreme, I have operated my camera above 40°C.
Not listed in the specifications is air speed. The external dust seal on my Nikon lens didn't fair too well, coming undone at 120 knot air speed.

I suggest starting out with a fully charged battery since battery life is reduced when the battery is cold. If you do a lot of shooting or take time exposures (aurora shots), it is wise to have a spare battery in an inner jacket pocket to keep it warm.

Unless someone can vouch for this camera, you'll need to take your chances that it will work in cold temperatures. I have a feeling that you'll be OK.
Cold temperatures won't damage the camera, but could have problems with the electronics and/or lens lubricants when cold. Electronics (unrelated to cameras) I take down to failure at -35°C come back to life when warmed up to -20°C.
As you are aware of, be sure to bag your camera before entering a building to prevent condensation. It takes about 45 minutes for the camera to come up to temperature.

Answer (score 2):

The spec sheet on their website says the operating range is 0°-40°**C** and humidity levels <= 85%.

https://www.canon.co.uk/cameras/eos-rp/specifications/

0° to 10°F is **-**18° to **-**12°C, much lower than your camera is certified for. Checking the forecast, I see the humidity can sometimes exceed 85%.

[image]

It MAY work, but you could cause permanent damage by using it in such lower temperatures. Your battery life will also be reduced; by how much is unknown.

Comment: 'Humidity' in this case is RELATIVE humidity at that temperature. The lower the temperature the less air can 'hold' water. So, at 0 F, there is little water in the air, but the relative humidity can be high (relative to what it can hold). The camera is designed for the extreme of the ranges, in this case 40 C and 85% relative humidity at that temperature (much more water vapor in air). So I would not worry about the humidity in Alaska in winter, which is very dry (ask your nose)

Comment: Specs don't distinguish between RH though, unfortunately, but I get your point.